# java - why is the hashcode() returning the same integer?

Tags: java, eclipse, object, hashcode

I am not exactly sure why the hashCode() method is returning the same value. Can someone provide more detailed explanation of this?

Source code (Java):

```
public class Equality {

public static void main(String [] args)
{
    String str = "String";
    String strOne = new String("String");



    System.out.println(str == strOne);
    System.out.println(str.equals(strOne));

    System.out.println(str.hashCode());
    System.out.println(strOne.hashCode());

}
```

}

Comment: Why do you think it should return a different hash code?

Comment: Why wouldn't it? They have the exact same value.

Comment: But they are different objects right? I know same objects have the same hashcode. But here str and strOne are different string objects right?

Comment: Please quote where you learned _same objects have the same hashcode._

Comment: @TarangHirani if two objects are equal according to their `.equals()` method then they are supposed to return the same hash code.

Comment: @TarangHirani Did you [read the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode())?

Comment: Yes, I have been reading the documentation to better understand the issue at hand. But im lost.

Answer (score 3):

From  the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) :

> The general contract of hashCode is:
>
> - Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an execution of a Java application, the hashCode method must consistently
>     return the same integer, provided no information used in equals
>     comparisons on the object is modified. This integer need not remain
>     consistent from one execution of an application to another execution
>     of the same application.
> - If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must
>     produce the same integer result.
> - It is not required that if two objects are unequal according to the equals(java.lang.Object) method, then calling the hashCode method
>     on each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results.
>     However, the programmer should be aware that producing distinct
>     integer results for unequal objects may improve the performance of
>     hash tables.

Basically, `a.equals(b) => a.hashCode() == b.hashCode()` so two identical strings will  surely have the same hashCode.

It seems to me that the behaviour you were expecting is the one of `==`, but it clearly is not. `==` is the strongest equality in Java, because it compares the location in memory of two objects. `equals` comes just after it, it is a logical equality, two objects can be `equal` even if they have different memory locations. The `hashCode` has the weakest properties, quoted above.

Comment: But my code is evaluating the hashcode method on different objects, namely, str and strOne. Am i correct in this logic?

Comment: They are different in terms of `==` (reference) but they are the same in terms of `equals` (logically equal)

Answer (score 1):

This should help your understanding. According to [the Java 7 docs for `String.hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode()) (I believe Java 6/8 should be similar or identical):

> ```
> public int hashCode()
> ```
>
> Returns a hash code for this string. The hash code for a `String` object is computed as
>
> ```
> s[0]*31^(n-1) + s[1]*31^(n-2) + ... + s[n-1]
> ```
>
> using `int` arithmetic, where `s[i]` is the *i*th character of the string, `n` is the length of the string, and `^` indicates exponentiation. (The hash value of the empty string is zero.)

Comment: I think the part that is confusing me is that they are two different objects but have the same hashcode. Rule of thumb says that if two objects are equal using the .equals method, they will have the hashcode. The fact that they are 2 different objects is confusing me. Help!

Comment: The documentation gives the formula for how they evaluate hash for String. They never refer to the reference of the object in this calculation.

Comment: Not sure why a down vote was given... I even gave the exact formula. :-)

Comment: @machsleep No, the *link* gave the exact formula. You didn't. Include the relevant bits that answer the question directly here, keeping the link as a reference, or add this as a comment instead. This is basically a link-only answer.

Comment: @TarangHirani try doing `"String".equals(new String("String"))`... it returns `true`, so what you said applies to this case : `two objects equal with the equal method have the same hashCode`

Comment: Should I just remember that as a rule of thumb?

Answer (score 0):

The `hasCode()` method applied on the value of `String`  which is "String" both case.

Although you have created two reference of `String` type like this -

```
String str = "String";
String strOne = new String("String");
```

But the hashCode() use the value assigned with the reference (`str` and `strONe`). Thats why the two `hashCode()` are equals.

Look at the hashCode() method of `String` class -

```
public int hashCode() {
    int h = hash;
        int len = count;
    if (h == 0 && len > 0) {
        int off = offset;
        char val[] = value;

            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                h = 31*h + val[off++];
            }
            hash = h;
        }
        return h;
    }
```

and `value` is declared like this -

```
private final char value[];
```